# what is "index.js?v=xxx" for?

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

[jupyter notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook) imports a bunch of javascript files when loading, almost all of them are in the URL pattern `.js?v=xxx`

[image]

I understand some URLs with parameters could be used for http get method.

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript
```

What is "index.js?v=xxx" for in jupyter notebook?

Here is part of `/static/components/proptypes/index.js`, click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tLb3jm78/1/) to see the full version

```
(function (global, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define('PropTypes', ['exports', 'module'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined' && typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    factory(exports, module);
  } else {
    var mod = {
      exports: {}
    };
    factory(mod.exports, mod);
    global.PropTypes = mod.exports;
  }
})
```

I compared

`http://localhost:8888/static/components/proptypes/index.js?v=c40890eb04df9811fcc4d47e53a29604` and

`http://localhost:8888/static/components/proptypes/index.js`

there is no any difference in them.

Is `function (global, factory)` to handle the parameter `v`?

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js?v=c40890eb04df9811fcc4d47e53a29604` and `https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js` are the same file while `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js` is newer.

Comment: It is probably the hash of the file or similar designator. Consider this: If the file changes the HTML will be returned with URLs using the new hash (or other identifier). This is a distinct resource name and _the browser will make a request for new resource (eg. scrip content) immediately, even if the site uses caching_. While the “v” is sent with the request, there is no reason that it must be used by the server (although it could be in cases where multi-versioned resources are supported).

Comment: might be for *cache-busting*

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you write your apps. I use version to force download updated javascript. Otherwise the browser will try to use existing cache and application will refuse to work accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Does "udated" mean latest version?

Comment: Yes, latest version. Also helps if i want to rollback

Comment: Thank you. `https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js?v=c40890eb04df9811fcc4d47e53a29604` and `https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js` are the same file while `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js` is newer.

Comment: When you pick directly from JQeury CDN you can access all the versions. Your web site is service, but your javascript files are not. So as mine (with some exception). So, when I update my javascript file I do not keep my old javascript version, JQuery has not decided to update https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js to latest.

Answer (score -1):

```
index.js?v=1.2
```

To make Fool client browser to Re-Load it from server and clear Cache of old file.